# Training a keras model on pretrained weights using load_weights()

Tags: tensorflow, keras, databricks

I am using a custom keras model in Databricks environment.
For a custom keras model, `model.save(model.h5)` does not work, because custom model is not serializable. Instead it is recommended to use `model.save_weights(path)` as an alternate.

`model.save_weights(pathDirectory)` works. This yields 3 files `checkpoint`,`.data-00000-of-00001`,`.index` in the pathDirectory

For loading weights, Following mechanism is working fine.

`model = Model()`

`model.load_weights(path)`

But I want to train my model on pretrained weights I just saved. Like I saved model weights, and continue training on these saved weights afterwards.

So, when I load model weights and apply training loop, I get this error, `TypeError: 'CheckpointLoadStatus' object is not callable`

Comment: Have you tried without the ".h5" at the end?

Comment: yes, I have tried many variations. ".h5", without extension, ".tf", ".hpy5" etc.

model.save() does not work in any case except ".hpy5", but then model.load(".hpy5") does not work.

Comment: Ok, are you re-compiling the model after loading the weights?

Comment: I am just doing this 
`model = model.load_weights(model_path)`

and then the training loop continues as usual

Comment: Ok I think you need to re-compile the model after loading the weights. Load weights only loads the weights, so you need to re-create the model structure (your layers), the optimizer and the loss and then compile them before fitting.

Comment: Delete that straight away - it contains passwords. Change your password for that immediately

Comment: It would help if you posted your code here and also posted the error

Comment: Please find it [here](https://gist.github.com/irfanumar1994/f38c3f80ac399717af5bce9904daa042) 
Loading model at line 108-110, and getting error at line 161, also commented in code.

Answer (score 0):

After much research, I have found a workaround,

we can also save model using
`model.save("model.hpy5")` and read it the saved model in databricks.

model.h5 not work for customized models, but it works for standard models.